# Application in EKS fails to access S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, amazon-eks

My application running in EKS (AWS Kubernetes) is failing to access an S3 bucket.

I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` errors in my app.

I suspect a permission is missing, so for testing I added **arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess** to any role I could find related to my EKS cluster. Still failing.

Using an S3 client from my local computer, I can access the bucket so I suspect I'm missing some configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: please share some of the actual IAM roles and configuration of the S3 bucket

Comment: @jaxxstorm - how do I see it? I created a bucket with my account and was able to upload to it with a dedicated user I created with AmazonS3FullAccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... issue was resolved. I'm leaving this here for future reference.

The problem was a mismatch of the bucket region, `us-west-2` and the endpoint I had configured in my application. It should have been `s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

The error returned by S3 was not clear.

I hope this helps others.